# Python Tkinter GUI "parent" not defined error and error on class declaration line, not sure what it means

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

The code below is giving me the error name "parent" not defined in line 25 and an error without a specific definition to what in line 13 with "class mainWindow". I'm not entirely sure what either of these mean and I am new to python and making GUI's. I've looked at GUI examples and can't find what I did wrong. Hoping someone can help debug this for me. :)

```
import sys, Tkinter
sys.modules['tkinter'] = Tkinter
import Pmw

class Print:

    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

    def __call__(self):
        print self.text

class mainWindow:

    def __init__(self,parent,balloon):
        self.balloon = Pmw.Balloon(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.menuBar = menuBar
        self.mainPart = mainPart
        self.buttonBox = buttonBox

    def Quit():
        root.destroy()

    menuBar = Pmw.MenuBar(parent,hull_relief = 'raised',hull_borderwidth = 1,balloon = self.balloon)
    menuBar.pack(fill = 'x')

    menuBar.addmenu('Run Control','Calibration,Download Configuration,Number of Triggers,Data Output File,Upload Configuration,Start DAQ,Quit')
    menuBar.addcascademenu('Run Control','Calibration','View and/or change the calibration',traverseSpec = 'z',tearoff = 1)
    menuBar.addmenuitem('Calibration','command','Display the DAC calibration',command = Print('display the DAC calibration'),label = 'Display DAC Calibration')

    menuBar.addmenuitem('Calibration','command','Display the calibration mask',command = Print('display the calibration mask'),label = 'Display Calibration Mask')
    menuBar.addmenuitem('Calibration','command','Change the DAC calibration',command = Print('change the DAC calibration'),label = 'Change DAC Calibration')
    menuBar.addmenuitem('Calibration','command','Change the calibration mask',command = Print('change the calibration mask'),label = 'Change Calibration Mask')

    menuBar.addmenuitem('Run Control','command','Download a configuration',command = Print('download configuration'),label = 'Download Configuration')

    menuBar.addmenuitem('Run Control','command','Set the number of triggers',command = Print('set number of triggers'),label = 'Number of Triggers')
    menuBar.addmenuitem('Run Control','command','Change the file where the data will be sent to',command = Print('set data output file'),label = 'Data Output File')
    menuBar.addmenuitem('Run Control','command','Upload a configuration',command = Print('upload a configuration'),label = 'Upload Configuration')

    menuBar.addmenuitem('Run Control','command','Start the data aquisition',command = Print('start data aquisition'),label = 'Start DAQ')
    menuBar.addmenuitem('Run Control','separator')
    menuBar.addmenuitem('Run Control','command','Close the GUI',command = Quit,label = 'Quit')

    mainPart = Tkinter.Label(parent,text = 'GUI',background = 'white',foreground = 'white',padx = 100,pady = 100)
    mainPart.pack(fill = 'both', expand = 1)

    buttonBox = Pmw.ButtonBox(parent)
    buttonBox.pack(fill = 'x')
    buttonBox.add('Start\nRoot', command = Print('start root'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    Pmw.initialise(root)
    root.title('pCT GUI')
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is the indentaion correct? It seems like everything from `def Quit` to `buttonBox.add` should still belong to `__init__`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an overview, the changes that I made were:

1. Shifting the code under the `__init__` method
2. Removing balloon as an argument from `__init__`
3. Moving the definitions for `self.buttonBox`,`self.menuBar`, and `self.mainPart` after the definitions for `buttonBox`,`menuBar`, and `mainPart` respectively.
4. Add a call to create an instance of your class `mainWindow`.

So as tobias mentioned in his comment, you need to indent the lines from `def Quit():` to `buttonBox.add`.

Next,  you need to add a line where you create an instance of the class by adding the following line to your main area

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    parent = Pmw.initialise(root)
    root.title('pCT GUI')
    derp = mainWindow(root) # <--- create your class
    root.mainloop()
```

Now you need to make a couple changes to your class definition.

First,  you do not need to have balloon as an argument for your `__init__` method, as you have initialize it on the first line in `__init__` method as `self.balloon = Pmw.Balloon(parent)` and do not reference the argument and never the argument that is passed.

Second, you need to move some of your declarations for the variables for the class

```
def __init__(self,parent):
    self.balloon = Pmw.Balloon(parent)        
    self.parent = parent


    def Quit():
        root.destroy()

    menuBar = Pmw.MenuBar(parent,hull_relief = 'raised',hull_borderwidth = 1,balloon = self.balloon)
    menuBar.pack(fill = 'x')

    menuBar.addmenu('Run Control','Calibration,Download Configuration,Number of Triggers,Data Output File,Upload Configuration,Start DAQ,Quit')

    # ...
    # ......
    # All the calls to menuBar in the lines above stay the same

    self.menuBar = menuBar   # This needs to be called AFTER you declare the variable
                             # and make your changes to it.

    mainPart = Tkinter.Label(parent,text = 'GUI',background = 'white',foreground = 'white',padx = 100,pady = 100)
    mainPart.pack(fill = 'both', expand = 1)

    self.mainPart = mainPart  # This needs to be called AFTER you declare the variable
                              # and make your changes to it.

    buttonBox = Pmw.ButtonBox(parent)
    buttonBox.pack(fill = 'x')
    buttonBox.add('Start\nRoot', command = Print('start root'))

    self.buttonBox = buttonBox   # This needs to be called AFTER you declare the variable
                                 # and make your changes to it.
```